# Photo rotates 90 degree after i take it with github/fusuma opensource

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm using fusuma project from github. If i select photo from library with fusuma and upload it to my server all is ok. But if i take photo from fusuma camera it rotates 90 degree. I tried to rotate it on php file but then it rotates all photos. 
Is there any solution for fusuma project? (swift language)

Comment: You need to handle the orientation of the image taken from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3

```
func fixOrientation(_image:UIImage) -> UIImage {

    if (_image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up) {
        return _image;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_image.size, false, _image.scale);
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: _image.size.width, height: _image.size.height)
    _image.draw(in: rect)

    let normalizedImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fusuma doesn't support landscape orientations, so you'll need to assume every picture it takes is in portrait. See https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma/issues/50#issuecomment-225333675